# Python/Django- Save csv file data with messy rows

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-models, csv-import

I have a csv file with the following structure:

```
A, 10
B, 11
C, 8
D, 12
A, 21
B, 7
D, 22
D, 15
C, 111
D, 50
A, 41
B, 32
C, 19
D, 11
```

I want to read the entire file, and save the data on the second column, if the row is like A, B, C, D format.
I have a list:

```
my_list = [A, B, C, D]
```

And I check each 4 row, if it is in `my_list` format, then read and save to the database like:

```
with open('csv_file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        the_file = csv.reader(csvfile.read().splitlines())

        for idx, row in enumerate(islice(zip(*[the_file]*4), 100)):
            my_model = Django_model()
            if row[0][0] == my_list[0]:
                if row[0][0] == my_list[0] and row[1][0] == my_list[1] and \
                    row[2][0] == my_list[2] and row[3][0] == my_list[3]:
                    my_model.a_field = row[0][1]
                    my_model.b_field = row[1][1]
                    my_model.c_field = row[2][1]
                    my_model.d_field = row[3][1]
                    my_model.save()
```

The fact is that it is working if and ONLY if the structure of the `row` is the same as `my_list`. But when it gets to the messy part (A, B, D, D, C, D) it will not read the rows properly, and therefore many rows are skipped.

The question is that, how can I jump to the next interesting row (which follows `my_list` format) and read it? Meanwhile save the the skipped rows in another list?

I have heard that Pandas could help, but I have been through the documentation, and I couldn't find a way to solve this case.

Comment: Check now. You can extract both the desired pattern and undesired pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the pattern and corresponding values like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv('/home/yusuf/Desktop/c1', header=None, names=['c1','c2'])
l1=[]
for a in re.finditer('ABCD', ''.join(df.c1.tolist())):
    l1.append(range(a.start(),a.end()))
l2 = [b for a in l1 for b in a]
print df[df.index.isin(l2)], '\n'
print df[~df.index.isin(l2)]
```

Output:

```
   c1  c2
0   A  10
1   B  11
2   C   8
3   D  12
10  A  41
11  B  32
12  C  19
13  D  11

  c1   c2
4  A   21
5  B    7
6  D   22
7  D   15
8  C  111
9  D   50
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems it is doing the job, but somehow, the first 2 rows are being skipped. And i get a list with: `C D A B C D` and the other one is: `A B A B D D C D`. Do you know what the reason could be?

Comment: I'll have to look at your code. The code I have provided works for the data you have included in the question. If you change either the data or the code then it might not work.

Comment: the only change i made is here: `for a in re.finditer(''.join(my_list), ''.join(df.c1.tolist()))` .
And `my_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` . Would this be a problem?

Comment: No that would be okay. The code will work with that change if the csv remains the same.

Comment: Thanks again for the solution, I am trying to debug, and I would like to know what does this do: `l2 = [b for a in l1 for b in a]` , because some of the good `A B C D` rows are appeared in the skipped rows list as well. I must add that I have a relatively large csv file with almost 1 million lines/rows.

Comment: It flattens out the list l1. `l1=[[0, 1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12, 13]]` and `l2=[0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13]`. These are index positions of ABCD in the dataframe. If you can upload that file somewhere and share the link, I'll see if I can help you out. Update that info in your question if you will.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130681/discussion-between-arrt-dtu-and-mohammad-yusuf-ghazi).